# More idiomatic way to initialize a set in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, initialization, set

I have a set of Cells
`data class Cell(val i: Int, val j: Int)`
that I initialize in my class like this

```
protected val board = mutableSetOf<Cell>()
init {
    for (i in 1..width) {
        for (j in 1..width) {
            board += Cell(i, j)
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more idiomatic (functional) way to initialize the set?
Ideally I would like the set to be immutable, because after this initialization it should never be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You could define an extension that takes in a transformer to get the combinations as a pair of integers, then map it to a `Cell`. For instance:

```
inline fun <R> IntRange.combine(block: (Int, Int) -> R): Set<R> {
    return flatMap { x -> map { y -> block(x, y) } }.toSet()
}
```

And then you can initialize with:

```
protected val board = (1..width).combine { x, y -> Cell(x, y) }
```

or simply:

```
protected val board = (1..width).flatMap { i -> (1..width).map { j -> Cell(i, j) } }
```

I think the former is more readable, though.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no constructor or top-level function to make the creation of a set following a certain logic easy, but if you already have a list you can turn it into a `Set` using `toSet()`.

In any case I would separate the logic of creating a list of combinations and the creation of the `Cell` instances.

```
// extension property on IntRange to create all possible combinations
val IntRange.combinations get() = flatMap { i -> map { j -> i to j }}

val set = (1..5)
             .combinations
             .map { (i, j) -> Cell(i, j) }
             .toSet()
```

**Addition:**

If you create a secondary constructor for `Cell` which takes a `Pair` like this:

```
data class Cell(val i: Int, val j: Int) {
    constructor(pair: Pair<Int, Int>): this(pair.first, pair.second)
}
```

you can shorten the code to this:

```
val set = (1..5).combinations.map(::Cell).toSet()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
fun initBoard(width: Int): Set<Cell> {
    return List<Cell>(width * width) { index ->
            val i = index / width
            val j = index % width
            Cell(i + 1, j + 1)
    }.toSet()
}
```

then in your init block

```
lateinit var board: Set<Cell>

init {
    board = initBoard(width)
}
```